# Mule and memory (RAM) usage

Tags: mule

i've tried to run mule on 3 cases in order to test it's mem usage:

- One case is where i had a quartz generator create an event that a filter (right after it in a flow) allways stopped (Returned false) - meaning the flow did absolutly nothing.
- In another case i did not use the filter but just used that flow to send a custom object to a WCF service running on another computer (using a cxf endpoint)
- Also, i've checked what happened when i leave the flow as is but drop the wcf servce (meaning a lot of socket connection exceptions were thrown).

I did this because i am building a large app that would need this bus to work at all times (weeks at a time).

In all of those cases, the mem usage kept rising. (getting as high as 200mb ram after a few hours)
Any specific reasons this could happen?? What is causing mule to take more memory, in all of these cases?

Comment: 150+MB of garbage is entirely possibly for the JVM to accumulate before triggering a GC, especially if you're keeping the process busy -- by load-testing or whatever. Is this possibly part of what you're seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head I'll stick with thread pool lazy initialization as explanation for this behavior. As time goes on and usage gets higher, the thread pools will get fully initialized.

If you want proof evidences take a look to [this](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Profiling+Mule) approach, or [this](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/JMX+Management) one (with enableStatistics).